# Is this an accepted way to join (left outer join table)?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

here is the setup-

```
           create table tasks (taskno int, customerno int);
           insert into tasks values (1, 100);
           commit;
           insert into tasks values (2, 200);
           commit;
           insert into tasks values (3, 300);
           commit;
           select * from tasks;

           create table items (taskno int, accountno int);
           commit;
           insert into items values (1, 1000);
           commit;
           insert into items values (2, 2000);
           commit;
           select * from items;

           create table accounts (accountno int, customerno int);
           commit;
           insert into accounts values (1000, 100);
           commit;
           insert into accounts values (1100, 100);
           commit;
           insert into accounts values (2000, 200);
           commit;
           insert into accounts values (3000, 300);
           commit;
           select * from accounts;
```

I want to get the taskno from tasks table based on an accountno. The tasks table only has something called customerno. This customerno can be associated with more than one accountno (think of customerno as a parent and accountno as children). So if you look at our setup, if I pass in accountno 1000 or 1100 both will return taskno 1 in this query -

```
           select a.taskno
           from tasks a, accounts c
           where a.customerno = c.customerno
           and c.accountno = 1000 -- but will return taskno 1 also for 1100
```

I want some more granular detail than this. So I found another table 'Items' which has the taskno and accountno. So if I added it to the query, it will correctly return the taskno 1 for accountno 1000 and not for 1100.

```
           select a.taskno
           from tasks a, items b, accounts c
           where a.taskno = b.taskno
           and a.customerno = c.customerno
           and c.accountno = b.accountno
           and c.accountno = 1000 -- nothing returned for 1100
```

This is all well and good but the Items table is not always reliable. It has lets say about only 90% of tasks found in Tasks table. So in this case when an task is not found in Items table, I want it from Tasks table, like accountno 3000 (this means I will have to go by customerno and will not have the granular level of accountno join. but it is ok). But when this accountno is found in Items, I want it to be used because it has the accountno, which gives me the taskno associated with the exact accountno. So I use the left outer join for Items with Tasks.

This works perfectly-

```
           select a.taskno
           from tasks a, items b, accounts c
           where a.taskno = b.taskno(+)
           and a.customerno = c.customerno
           and c.accountno = nvl(b.accountno, c.accountno)
           and c.accountno = 3000 -- will return taskno 3


           select a.taskno
           from tasks a, items b, accounts c
           where a.taskno = b.taskno(+)
           and a.customerno = c.customerno
           and c.accountno = nvl(b.accountno, c.accountno)
           and c.accountno = 1000 --returns 1 and nothing returned for 1100
```

My question is have I constructed the query here correctly - specially the part where I am linking Items to Accounts with NVL? Is this the expected way to do this? Or is this a weird round about way?

Comment: Well, the first thing you're going to be told here, is: use ANSI join syntax!

Comment: Even Oracle recommends to stop using the implicit outer joins in the where clause using the proprietary `(+)` and use an explicit `LEFT JOIN` (or `RIGHT JOIN`) operator.

Comment: I don't understand why you are joining with the `items` table if you are selecting from the `tasks` table only, and filtering by an `accounts` table field, and both tables are joinable.  Why do you need to include `items` in the query?  Unless you are selecting information from `items` as well, but you didn't show that.

Comment: @sstan - I am using Items table because it has accountno, which is more granular that customerno which is in Tasks. For example, if I don't join the items to this query, if I pass in accountno 1100 as an input, the query will return taskno 1. But taskno1 is for accountno 1000. The reason query works like this is because both 1000 and 1100 has same customerno (100). In these types of cases I want to dip into Items table because it has the accoutno.But l cant completely omit Tasks and only use Items because Items doesn't contain all the data I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, your query does work, and is quite clever.  But it's hard to read and understand, in part because of the join syntax used.  Translated using ANSI joins, we get:

```
select t.taskno
  from accounts a
  join tasks t
    on t.customerno = a.customerno
  left join items i
    on i.taskno = t.taskno
 where a.accountno = 1100
   and a.accountno = nvl(i.accountno, a.accountno)
```

I still feel that the intent is not very clear.

Personally, I would rewrite the query to move the logic of the left join inside a `not exists` clause instead.  It just seems to me that it better expresses the intent, and it works just as well.

In ANSI join syntax:

```
select t.taskno
  from accounts a
  join tasks t
    on t.customerno = a.customerno
 where a.accountno = 1100
   and not exists (select null
                     from items i
                    where i.taskno = t.taskno
                      and i.accountno <> a.accountno)
```

Same query in legacy join syntax, if it helps you better understand (but try to move away from this syntax if possible):

```
select t.taskno
  from accounts a, tasks t
 where a.accountno = 1100
   and t.customerno = a.customerno
   and not exists (select null
                     from items i
                    where i.taskno = t.taskno
                      and i.accountno <> a.accountno)
```